# Azure Devops unable to populate picklist

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-pipelines-task-lib

I followed the tutorial found at 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops

The api call is right because if I don't authenticate it shows the correct path in the error message.  Entering the url  that it shows in the message in a browser gives the correct json.

The picklist object will act like it is trying to load but will end up showing no results found.

Can you use a personal company api to load a picklist using server endpoint?

How do you debug this.  All I see in the network tab on debugging tools is the 200 from azure making the post.

````
This is the JSON 
{
  "meta": {
    "record_count": 5,
    "source": "mongodb",
    "searchParams": {
      "versions.start_date": {
        "$gte": "2019-08-30T00:11:55.329Z"
      }
    },
    "paging": {
      "num": 10,
      "start": 0
    }
  },
  "screenshots": [
    {
      "screenshot_test_id": 3946619,
      "url": "https://www.google.com",
      "test_name": null,
      "created_date": "2019-10-27T21:26:32.0 ```



This is the datasources from the vss.extension
"dataSources": [
          {
            "name": "CBTAPIReturn",
            "endpointUrl": "{{endpoint.url}}",
            "resultSelector": "jsonpath:$[*].screenshots"

          }

        ]

inputs and bindings from the task

"inputs": [
    {
      "name": "CBTService",
      "type": "connectedService:CBTServiceEndpoint",
      "label": "CBT service/server end point",
      "defaultValue": "",
      "required": true,
      "helpMarkDown": "Select the CBT end point to use. If needed,selecton 'manage', and add a new service endpoint of type 'CBT server connection'"
    },
    {
      "name": "CBT API Response",
      "type": "pickList",
      "label": "CBT API Response",
      "required": true,
      "helpMarkDown": "Select the name combination that you want to use.",
      "properties": {
        "EditableOptions": "True"
      }
    }
  ],
  "dataSourceBindings": [
    {
      "target": "CBT API Response",
      "endpointId": "$(CBTService)",
      "dataSourceName": "CBTAPIReturn"
    ```
````